# Matching backticks using matchit --- possible?

Tags: vim, restructuredtext

I'm writing a lot of RST lately and I would like the `%` keystroke to match between grave accent (i.e. backtick) characters.

```
`The cursor is at the |vertical line`
```

and then hitting `%` moves the cursor as shown

```
`The cursor is at the vertical line|`
```

I have tried setting the `b:match_words` for the `matchit` plugin but that doesn't help.

Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forgive me for tooting my own horn, but I am an expert on the matchit plugin.

Although it is designed to extend the built-in matching functionality, matchit extends it in several ways.  For one, it allows you to match regular expressions, not just single characters.  You can get very good results by using vim's start-of-word and end-of-word patterns:

```
:let b:match_words='`\<:\>`'
```

This certainly works on the one-line example you gave.  Similarly, you might decide that the starting <kbd>`</kbd> usually does not have a non-whitespace character before it, and the closing one is not followed by a non-whitespace character.  (If that is too many negatives, then "This is markup" usually starts a new line or follows a space or tab; and it is usually followed by the end of a line or a space or tab.)  Then you could use

```
:let b:match_words='\S\@<!`:`\S\@!'
```

The matchit plugin tries to live up to vim's design goals, including `:help design-documented`.  The standard vim distribution includes both `matchit.vim` (the script) and `matchit.txt` in `$VIMRUNTIME/macros/`.  You can either read the documentation there or follow the instructions at `:help matchit-install` and browse the documentation with `:help`.

Under `:help b:match_words`, it says,

```
Tips: Be careful that your initial pattern does not match your final pattern.
```

This is because, when you bang on the <kbd>%</kbd> key, the script has to be able to figure out whether it is on the starting pattern or the ending pattern.  The only information it has to make this decision is what you have told it in `b:match_words`.

Comment: Thank you for all your work on this powerful plug-in!

Comment: Thanks for all the information .I am trying to match `ifdef |`ifndef:`else:`endif but it does not work for me. This is Systemverilog syntax

Comment: That sounds like a new question. It is hard to debug "it does not work" wityout seeing what you have tried.

Have you looked at the documentation mentioned in my answer? Have you checked the ftplugins included with vim? There are several other lauages that need to do something similar, and you can probably use one of them as a model.

Answer (score 0):

The matchit plugin is designed to work similar to the built-in `%` command and as such suffers some of the same limitations. In particular, from `:help 'matchpairs'`:

```
Only character pairs are allowed that are different, thus you cannot
jump between two double quotes.
```

Thus, this works as expected (but not as you want):

```
:let b:match_words="`:'"
```

But this does not work:

```
:let b:match_words="`:`"
```

Answer (score 0):

For some suggestions how to pair identical delimiters with `matchit` in common prose or markup files, such as `rst`, see my [repository](https://github.com/Konfekt/matchit-for-markup.vim/).